# In Go_Router package, how to hide StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack? I tried using keys but I just can not make it work

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have a page called 'clubview' which is inside the StatefulShellRoute. When a user is in this page he can navigate to another page called 'createClub'.

I need a way to show BottomNavigationBar whenever I want, in this case I want it to show when a user is in the 'clubview' and not when they push 'createClub'. I can make it work if i use GoNamed but then I can not go back by doing pop(). So, is there a way to show BottomNavigationBar only in certain routes while using pushNamed?

my code looks partially like this:

note: I could even make 'createClub' a subroute of 'clubview' but even that I can not make it work. Tried searching on the web but there is very limited resources about StatefulShellRoute.indexStack

```
      GoRouter(
        navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
        initialLocation: initialLocation,
        refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(authBloc.stream),
        redirect: (context, state) {
          if (authBloc.state is AuthUnauthenticatedState) {
            if (state.location == Routes.login.path ||
                state.location == Routes.register.path ||
                state.location.startsWith(Routes.passwordreset.path)) {
              return null;
            } else if (state.location == Routes.verifyemail.path ||
                state.location == Routes.chooseName.path) {
              return Routes.register.path;
            } else {
              return Routes.login.path;
            }
          } else if (authBloc.state is AuthChooseNameState &&
              state.location != Routes.chooseName.path) {
            return Routes.chooseName.path;
          } else if (authBloc.state is AuthVerifyEmaildState &&
              state.location != Routes.verifyemail.path) {
            return Routes.verifyemail.path;
          } else if (authBloc.state is AuthAuthenticatedState &&
              (state.location == Routes.login.path ||
                  state.location == Routes.register.path ||
                  state.location == Routes.chooseName.path ||
                  state.location == Routes.verifyemail.path)) {
            return Routes.clubview.path;
          } else if (authBloc.state is ColdStartLogin &&
              (state.location == Routes.login.path ||
                  state.location == Routes.register.path ||
                  state.location == Routes.chooseName.path ||
                  state.location == Routes.verifyemail.path)) {
            return Routes.clubview.path;
          } else {
            //if (state.location == Routes.createClub.path ||
            //    state.location == Routes.mediaPicker.path) {
            //  BlocProvider.of<InstantFadecubit>(context).hideBottomBar();
            //} else {
            //  BlocProvider.of<InstantFadecubit>(context).showBottomBar();
            //}
            return null;
          }
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.home.name,
            path: Routes.home.path,
            builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.login.name,
            path: Routes.login.path,
            builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.register.name,
            path: Routes.register.path,
            builder: (context, state) => const RegisterPage(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.chooseName.name,
            path: Routes.chooseName.path,
            builder: (context, state) => const ChooseName(),
          ),
          StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
              return DashboardScreen(key: state.pageKey, child: navigationShell);
            },
            branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
              StatefulShellBranch(
                //navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                      name: Routes.clubview.name,
                      path: Routes.clubview.path,
                      builder: (context, state) => const ClubView()),
                ],
              ),
              StatefulShellBranch(
                //navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.searchEngine.name,
                    path: Routes.searchEngine.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const SearchEngine(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              StatefulShellBranch(
                //navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.mapa.name,
                    path: Routes.mapa.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const Map1(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              StatefulShellBranch(
                //navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.profile.name,
                    path: Routes.profile.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const Profile(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.verifyemail.name,
            path: Routes.verifyemail.path,
            builder: (context, state) => const VerifyEmail(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            path: '${Routes.passwordreset.path}/:email',
            name: Routes.passwordreset.name,
            builder: (context, state) => PasswordReset(
              email: state.pathParameters['email']!,
            ),
          ),
          GoRoute(
              //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
              path: Routes.passwordreset.path,
              name: '${Routes.passwordreset.name}null',
              builder: (context, state) => const PasswordReset()),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            path: Routes.clubpage.path,
            name: Routes.clubpage.name,
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state.extra is ClubOverview) {
                final club = state.extra as ClubOverview;
                return ClubPage(club: club);
              } else {
                final club =
                    ClubOverview.fromMap(state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>);
                return ClubPage(club: club);
              }
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.createClub.name,
            path: Routes.createClub.path,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return CustomTransitionPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                child: const ClubForm(),
                transitionsBuilder:
                    (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                  return Transform.scale(
                    scale: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).evaluate(animation),
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.createPost.name,
            path: Routes.createPost.path,
            builder: (context, state) {
              final club = state.extra as ClubProfile;
              return CreatePost(clubProfile: club);
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            //parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.mediaPicker.name,
            path: Routes.mediaPicker.path,
            builder: (context, state) {
              final Map<String, dynamic> extraData =
                  state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>;
              // Extract any necessary parameters from the state.extra if needed
              final maxCount = extraData['maxCount'] as int;
              final requestType = extraData['requestType'] as RequestType;
              return ImageMediaPicker(
                  maxCount: maxCount, requestType: requestType);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
```

show and hide BottomNavigationBar depending on the route using go_router StatefulShellRoute.indexStack while also using pushnamed to navigate routes

Answer (score 0):

add _rootNavigatorKey for createClub Route